# Django Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '/run/gunicorn.sock:'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035

Tags: python, django, http-headers

I need some help. I've a Django website, i added admin notification and Django keep sending me Invalid HTTP_HOST header notification.

The complete error message is

> [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '/run/gunicorn.sock:'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

Here is my Nginx configuration

```
server {
    
    if ($host !~ ^(XX.XX.XX.XX|example.com|www.example.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    } # Deny illegal Host headers
 
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

  
    listen 80; 
    server_name example.com www.example.com XX.XX.XX.XX;                             
    access_log off; 
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 

}

server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com XX.XX.XX.XX;

    if ($host !~ ^(XX.XX.XX.XX|example.com|www.example.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    } # Deny illegal Host headers

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /assets/ {
        root /home/joe/example;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/joe/example;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: `proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;` Are you sure that format is correct?

Comment: @JohnGordon i'm not doing well at server configuration. I followed instructions from digital ocean.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that nginx is passing the host name as is.
You can update the host header:

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host; // Add this
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
```

and comment in the `proxy_params` file:

```
# proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```